# Assign html and var value smarty php

Tags: php, smarty

I need to assign value for smarty var but it need to be mixed with some html or text 
like

```
 {assign var="heading1" value='Hello $user <a href="#">logout</a>'}
```

HTML works but the `$user` variable does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to embed your PHP variable, you must use double quotes in `smarty`.

For instance:

```
{assign var="heading1" value="Hello $user <a href='#'>logout</a>"}
```

should concatenate $user for you.

Comment: does not work , it's is amember var $smarty.session._amember_user.login

Comment: It does work. Your value for $user is not what you expect as output. It does concatenate your value for you. Find out what you want as output and replace $user accordingly.

Comment: I had to assign the ammeber var first than it worked. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In Smarty2 you would (for "complex variables" like `$foo.bar.baz`) write something like

```
{assign var="heading1" value="Hello `$user` <a href='#'>logout</a>"}
```

in Smarty3 you could do

```
{$heading1 = "Hello {$user} <a href='#'>logout</a>"}
```

---

If you want that variable to be escaped (and yes, you want that), you could use a [{capture}](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.capture.tpl):

```
{capture assign="heading1"}Hello {$user|escape} <a href='#'>logout</a>{/capture}
```

In Smarty3 you could do

```
{$heading1 = "Hello {$user|escape} <a href='#'>logout</a>"}
```